# How to use std::invoke_result_t in c++17 or 20 instead of std::result_of_t in c++14?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, metaprogramming, c++20

when I use std::result_of_t in c++14 it's doing as i wish:

```
void just_simple()
{
    std::cout << "【4】: in func return nothing. " << std::endl;
}

template<typename Callback, typename... Args>
auto InTemplate_Call(Callback&& bc, Args&&... args)
{
    typedef typename std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Callback>(std::decay_t<Args>...)> ReturnType;

    //typedef typename std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<Callback>(std::decay_t<Args>...)> ReturnType;

    if (typeid(ReturnType) == typeid(void))
    {
        std::cout << "get a void type" << std::endl;
    }

    return rtDeduction<ReturnType>::type();
}

int main(){
    InTemplate_Call(just_simple);

    return 0;
}
```

The `ReturnType` is just `void`.

But It's not work in c++17 or 20:

```
template<typename Callback, typename... Args>
auto InTemplate_Call(Callback&& bc, Args&&... args)
{
    //typedef typename std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Callback>(std::decay_t<Args>...)> ReturnType;

    typedef typename std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<Callback>(std::decay_t<Args>...)> ReturnType;

    if (typeid(ReturnType) == typeid(void))
    {
        std::cout << "get a void type" << std::endl;
    }

    return rtDeduction<ReturnType>::type();
}
```

The `ReturnType` is not `void` anymore!

Is there anything I made mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `invoke_result` and `result_of` is that the former accepts the callable type and arguments type, but your `std::decay_t<Callback>(std::decay_t<Args>...)` is just a **function type** that returns a `std::decay_t<Callback>`.

The following shows the differences:

```
#include <functional>

void just_simple() {}

template<typename Callback>
void foo(Callback&&)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<Callback()>, Callback>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<Callback  >, void>);
}

int main() {
  foo(just_simple);
}
```

You should do this:

```
typedef typename std::invoke_result_t<
  std::decay_t<Callback>, 
  std::decay_t<Args>...> ReturnType;
```

Comment: The `typename` keyword is unnecessary. Also think `using` is easier to read than `typedef`, since C++11 is already assumed here, but I guess that's a personal preference.